# association between three models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models

good day in this working association that I'm trying to do, using nested_form

```
#_form.html.erb in post
<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
  <% address.association :state  %>
<% end %>

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
end



class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :states
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses  
end
```

print the error: Association :state not found!!!
help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

> ```
> class Book < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :author
> end
> ```
>
> belongs_to associations must use the singular term. If you used the
>   pluralized form in the above example for the author association in the
>   Book model, you would be told that there was an "uninitialized
>   constant Book::Authors". This is because Rails automatically infers
>   the class name from the association name. If the association name is
>   wrongly pluralized, then the inferred class will be wrongly pluralized
>   too.

So you must replace the line:

```
belongs_to :states
```

with

```
belongs_to :state
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `State` class code.

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

You have used `states` instead of `state`. Hence, you are getting the error.